# Prepend country and language before the controller example.com/{country}/{language}/home

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have been asked to create multi country page that should have a different base url depending on the type of page.

For most pages it should be example.com/{country}/{language}/home for some it will be just /{country}/ and for some just /{language}/

The idea is to be able to SEO optimize pages without having duplicate content, it should allow for any country and any language combination so using 1 parameter for things like it-it wont work.

I'm new to net core and don't an idea on how to approach this solution.

Comment: What's the need for adding the country into the url? General approach would be to add language preference into the url / use  a culture cookie. Is supporting multiple routes such as ....com/{country}/{language}/home, ....com/{country}/home, ...com/{language}/home etc what you really need? The following links should help you: [Link1](https://dzone.com/articles/aspnet-core-simple-localization-and-language-based) [Link2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Yes unfortunately the argument is to be able to seo optimize /uk/en pages for the uk and /es/es/ pages for spain.
I find their approach overkill but it's the SEO company that is pushing this implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@eVolve provided the solution.

using this repository i was able to do what i needed.
https://github.com/gpeipman/AspNetCoreLocalization

The trick was using asp-route-{value} tag helpers that when combined with the map routes it allows paths to be set.

```
<li asp-route-country="uk" asp-route-lang="ru"><a asp-controller=@currentController asp-action=@currentAction asp-route-country="uk" asp-route-lang="ru">uk ru</a></li>

 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "LocalizedDefaultcl",
                template: "{country:country}/{lang:lang}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"

            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "LocalizedDefault",
                template: "{lang:lang}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "LocalizedDefaultCountry",
                template: "{country:country}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );
```